# new line for xml format

Tags: c#, xml

string sample = "name mike"

when i see the output in console it displays like `<name></name><mike></mike>`
But i want the output like

```
<name></name>
<mike></mike>
```

tags doesnot come in next line in the console.

Comment: Use Json.Net to deserialize the Json input to objects, then use XmlSerializer to serialize the objects to XML.

Comment: PS this isn't a valid Json file - no colons, no double quotes around names or string values. You can't parse it using any Json library

Comment: Oops .. Then is there a way to convert this to the desired o/p that i posted.

Comment: You can parse any format you like but before you start writing a parser it's a good idea to write the BNF for whatever it is you are trying to parse. I wouldn't start from one example record.

Answer (score 2):

The first you need is a correct json, the provided example is not correct, it should look like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Mike",
    "age": 19,
    "gender": "male"
}
```

Using the json.net library that you can find here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Open the file and deserialize it in xml using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode` and providing the rootElementName that in your case should be Person or the name of the class.

You will get something like this:

```
<person>
  <Name>Mike</Name>
  <age>19</age>
  <gender>male</gender>
</person>
```

Example:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(resultPath, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileRequested),"person").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input always looks the same you could try it with a simple regex in this manner:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{(\w+)\s(\w+)\}");
string input = @"{ {Name Mike} {age 19} {gender male}}";
string outputTemplate = @"<a text = ""{0}"" value = ""{1}"" />";
if (r.IsMatch(input))
{
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string key = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
        string value = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(outputTemplate, key, value);
    }
}
```